# What is the difference between "à" and "en"?

Tags: prépositions

I think that “à” and “en” both mean “in” in English, right?

But, what is the difference between their usage? I mean, when do we use each?

Comment: No, *à* and *en* do not necessarily mean "in". This kind of information can be found very easly on the web. For instance [here](http://www.francaisfacile.com/exercices/exercice-francais-2/exercice-francais-20423.php) or [here](http://www.french.hku.hk/starters/structures/04_prepositions.htm) etc...